# Sunken area under bathroom cabinets

Tags: bathroom, concrete, floor, remodeling

I'm remodeling a bathroom in a Houston, TX house that was built in 1969. After removing the cabinets on each side, I found that the concrete floor is approximately 2 inches lower where the cabinets were. Why would they do that and can I just fill it in with concrete?

enter image description here

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Any pictures (just because I haven't seen that before)?  What are your plans for that space - more cabinets?

Comment: I'm planning more cabinets on most of it and tile on a small part of it. I'll take pics today.

Comment: Is the plumbing exceptionally low on the wall?  I agree filling with concrete seems like the best move, just trying to figure out why that would have been done in the first place.

Comment: If you can post a link to the pics, someone with more reputation can add them to the question (me).

Comment: That link doesn't seem to work, but it looks like [anyone, even new users can upload images](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/43874).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I need to go back to the original post. I'm learning.

Comment: Thanks, that's very interesting.  It does look like the floor was "built up" around the cabinets for whatever reason.  I agree with JACK that leaving the recess would be a big issue if water leaked into the "holes".

Comment: The problem with the built up around the cabinets idea is that the floor would be higher than the hall that it's attached to. Unless the whole bathroom was a sunken bathroom for some strange reason.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this one time where some self leveling concrete was added to a poorly poured floor after the cabinets were installed. You'll probably never really know why unless you contact the previous owners or even the ones before them. You would probably be better off just filling in the space with concrete because any water leaks or spills will just sit in there until they evaporate, causing mold and mildew.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds about right. Very puzzling though.